# snapscroll plugin not activating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get snapscroll to work as per the documentation but can't quite get it to behave. It says "SnapScroll only works with containers set to 100% window height for single page sites."

Snapscroll: http://wtm.github.io/jquery.snapscroll/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L649M/1/

```
$(function() {
$(".content").snapscroll();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin requires that the children should be within a single wrapping element.
Your HTML shows that the `.content` are one wrapper for each `.stuff`.
Your HTML setup should be like this one:

```
 <div class="content"> 
    <div class="stuff" style="background-color:#D95153;"> </div>
    <div class="stuff"  style="background-color:#967D7D;"> </div>
    <div class="stuff"  style="background-color:#ADA1A2;"> </div> 
 </div>
```

You may also use jQuery in order to make each child a 100% height as the window.
Also, in order to work properly, call the plugin after it was constructed.
So after the plugin constructor you should place this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".stuff").height($(window).height());
  $(".content").snapscroll();
});
```

[CHECK THIS UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L649M/8/)